# Kendall's tau for holdouts low and not significant - Conjoint

Tags: spss, validation, out-of-sample, conjoint-analysis, kendall-tau

I have done my Conjoint Analysis (fractional factorial design) but when it comes to validating the model, it shows a Kendall's tau for Holdouts of 0.33 and not significant.
But Pearson's R and Kendall's tau are high and significant which is supposed to show that the fit of my model is good...

How do I interpret this result? When I remove 2 of my 4 holdouts, then it shows perfect Kendall's tau & significant...But I can't just take 2 holdouts out to 'make it work'...

Thanks for your help.

PS: Also, for my understanding, what regression or analysis is that conjoint command in SPSS running exactly?